# Why is my method undefined?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

So super  simple, am trying to get into google apps scripting, and I am extremely rusty with javascript. I have created the sidebar in google sheets, and I have two documents, the gs document and the html document. I am trying to have a button display some text in said sidebar, and the function that the button calls is in the .gs file. However for some reason it is not running. Upon checking the console, the error I am getting is Uncaught ReferenceError getData is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (userCodeAppPanel:1) Please explain to me why this is not working. I have spent two days trying to figure this out.

to simplify, I have a method in the html file (getdata()), that is supposed to run when the button is pressed. However the function is sitting in code.gs and I cannot figure out why it is not beeing called.

html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">

    <style>
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #3498DB;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #2980B9;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd}

.show {display:block;}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    Hello, world! 
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
       <div class="dropdown">
         <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
         <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#home">Home</a>
            <a href="#about">About</a>
            <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
         </div>
       </div>
       <div class="testButton">

         <button onclick="getData()">Gather Data</button>

       </div>
       <p id="testData"></p>
<script>
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}


</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

code.gs file

```
// display the sidebar
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}
var page;
function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('page')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
  page = html;
}

function getData (){

  //var result = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange('check in/invoice!A2:E670').getValues();
  //var numRows = result.values ? result.values.length : 0;
  Logger.log('this is running');
  //document.getElementbyId('testData').innerHTML='you have clicked the button';

}
```

Comment: _I have a method in the html file (getdata()),_ -- no, you don't. Where are you including `code.gs`? Without including your source code, the function cannot be found.

Comment: The only mistake in the code is the fact that you didn't include the script file.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that your html file and the javascript associated with it runs in your browser while the code in code.gs runs on the server. You cannot include code.gs in your html file.

You can call from html back to the server using `google.script.run`

In your case:

```
google.script.run.getData();
```

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) as this is a very important fundamental concept for this type of programming. Remember that the call will be asynchronous and that you will need to implement success and error handlers if you want to do something with the result or trap errors.